# M2 Certification Exam question?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, certification

Will M2 Professional Developer exam have questions from Version 2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the 'About The Exam' section on https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer you'll see it lists:

- Based on Magento Open Source (2.2) and Magento Commerce (2.2), but applicable to those using any version of Magento 2.

Based on this I doubt it will have any specific Magento 2.3 questions in it.